# Maximum width and height for ImageView in Android

Tags: android, resize, imageview, android-imageview, stretch

So I have an ImageView set with

```
android:maxHeight="100px"
android:maxWidth="250px"
android:minHeight="100px"
android:minWidth="250px"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

This image view is used to show a picture that is obtained from the gallery or camera. In both cases, the image is not resized to fit inside the imageview, it just stretches its space as much as it needs.

Any idea how to make it stay inside those bounds?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtSubject"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:height="80px"
    android:hint="@string/description"></EditText>

<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDescription"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/txtMorada"
    android:hint="@string/address" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtMorada"
    android:id="@+id/btGPS"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_compass"></ImageButton>

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btGPS"
    android:layout_marginTop="25px"
    android:id="@+id/imgPoint"
    android:src="@drawable/google_logo_small"
    android:maxHeight="100px"
    android:maxWidth="250px"
    android:minHeight="100px"
    android:minWidth="250px"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"></ImageView>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPoint"
    android:id="@+id/btGallery"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btCamera"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageButton>

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:id="@+id/btSubmit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btGallery"
    android:text="@string/submit"></Button>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btMap"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtMorada"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_mapmode"></ImageButton>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtMorada"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btMap"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lblNewPointLatitude"
    android:text="Latitude"></TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btMap"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lblNewPointLongitude"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblNewPointLatitude"
    android:text="Longitude"></TextView>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_below="@+id/btMap"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+is/imgPoint"
    android:id="@+id/btCamera"
    android:layout_marginTop="25px"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageButton>

<Spinner
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spCategoria"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:prompt="@string/spCategoriaPrompt"></Spinner>

<Spinner
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spSubcategoria"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spCategoria"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:prompt="@string/spSubcategoriaPrompt"></Spinner>

<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spSubcategoria"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/txtSubject"
    android:hint="@string/subject"></EditText>

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What is the layout surrounding the ImageView?  Can you post a bigger snippet of the xml?

Comment: You should really add line breaks with indentation to your XML, too. It's unreadable as is. One thing I noticed offhand was in the btCamera TextView: Your layout_toRightOf says `@+is` instead of `@+id`. That's not your main problem, of course, but it'll affect your layout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android imageview not respecting maxWidth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530328/android-imageview-not-respecting-maxwidth)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Try the [`adjustViewBounds`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) attribute:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 7):

have you tried [android:scaleType="fitCenter"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)? Also the dimensions of the view should not be set to `wrap_content` as pointed out by Mayra

Answer (score 7):

you have both `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`, in addition to setting explicit values for width and height.  Instead, you should just set layout_width and layout_height to some number value.  Also, use dp instead of px.  See [supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: You cannot set layout_width/height to integer values in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Try including this: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
Example :

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="400dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:src="@drawable/background_img"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

While all the answers already mentioned, it is required to add

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

it should be also noted that **scaling does not work if `android:background` is used** to set the image. To allow scaling make use of `src` or `srcCompat` like

```
<!-- Will not work -->
android:background="@drawable/my_image"

<!-- Works -->
android:src="@drawable/my_image"
<!-- Works -->
app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_image"
```