# Android VideoView Sizes

Tags: android, layout, android-videoview

I have a VideoView in one of my Android app and have following code.

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/mainVideo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="200dip" android:maxWidth="300dip"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true">
</VideoView>
```

When I see this in design view, it doesn't work. I want the sizes to wrap but at max size written. If you see this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530328/android-imageview-not-respecting-maxwidth), you will realize how similar thing works for the ImageView setting **android:adjustViewBounds** property to **true**.

Comment: What's not working? If you're using it for video, wrap_content has no content to wrap until you start playing a video.

Comment: So you mean, it won't work in design mode but at the run time?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "work". The view doesn't yet know the size of the content, since the content haven't been added yet, so it can't wrap it either.

Comment: you are using minWidth, rather than maxWidth.check that out

Comment: @Kumar, I just noticed it now. Let me try your both receipe

Comment: Didn't work either with maxHeight and maxWidth at runtime. The VideoView goes outside of screen bounds even I have written 200dip as max height.