# ImageView not keeping max height and width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml

I load an image into an `ImageView` using `.setImageURI(selectedImageUri)` that is retrieved from the user's photo gallery. I have the image view restrict the size with

```
android:maxHeight="150dp"
android:minHeight="150dp" 
android:maxWidth="150dp" 
android:minWidth="150dp"
```

It's fine up until the you add the image from the gallery. The image then forgets about the max height and width. It is as wide as the display and there is a lot of space above and below the image. I had to add a scrollview just to see the image and scroll down. there is an even amount of space above and below. Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android imageview not respecting maxWidth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530328/android-imageview-not-respecting-maxwidth)

Comment: If rest answers are not working for you
visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317310/6332104

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Add the following to your [XML code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) (Or use the [appropriate function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds%28boolean%29))

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

I don't know why this isn't a default, because it seems like it would be required for a large number of items. Still, adding this simple logic to your XML file will make all of the difference.

Comment: @MrAppleBR: You have no idea how long this took me to figure out... Glad to be of service!

Comment: @Aggressor if you need a fixed value you don't need setMaxWidth and setMinWidth, just set android:layout_width="50dp"

Comment: @Aggressor You also should avoid using fixed widths like that unless you have a very specific case. The reason that works on iOS is you know what your screen size and resolution is. In Android it is very variable.

Comment: @zgc7009 Unless you...dynamically generate the width value from a percent of the screen size ;)

Answer (score 2):

I  havent. So, I ll be just guessing

1. Did you try defining a [ScaleType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951923/whats-the-default-scaletype-of-imageview) option?
2. Check for opposing layout attributes that can cause the layout inflater to ignore the desired width/height 
   values.
3. I suppose you tried this already but use just Layout_height /Layout_width instead of min/max attributes..

Comment: Thanks! I i forgot you can put actual numbers in the Layout height/width :O